# was ist richtig HIER oder DA?

Tags: word-choice

Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, 
ich habe eine Frage, und zwar: In einem Text wurde geschrieben:

1- Mit Ihrer Reiseleitung haben wir uns am 12.12.2016 gegen 10 Uhr in Verbindung gesetzt! Wir bekamen auch ................. keine Hilfe.

2- und weiter gehts; Obwohl wir mehfach darum baten, mussten wir bis zu unserer Abreise .............. bleiben.

Die Frage: Der erste Satz beschreibt eine bestimmte Zeitangabe, mit Gewissheit und ohne Zweifel, deshalb habe ich sofort -------  DA -----  geschrieben.

Der zweite Satz beschreibt eine Lokaleangabe bzw. wir müssen in diesem Ort oder in diesem Hotel bis zum Ende unsers Aufenthaltes bleiben, deshalb habe ich sofort mit --- Hier --- geantwortet.

Dann habe ich gesucht obwohl mir das schon bekannt war, und habe im Duden auch gefunden, dass HIER am häufigsten als Lokaleangabe gebraucht wird, und an der letzten Stelle als Temporaleangabe.

Jemand sagte zu mir am Anfang .. ja das hat mit der Zeit was zu tun, dann habe ich ihm diesen Grund vernichtet, weil der ganze Text in der Vergangenheit geschrieben wurde und meistens mit Präteritum. Und dann sagte derselbe zu mir: "man sagt nicht auf deutsch: 'ich war gestern HIER', sondern 'ich war gestern DA'".

Das klingt natürlich komisch an, denn ich lerne deutsch seit 3 Jahren und es ist ganz oft häufiger gesagt: "Ich war gestern hier"! Klar, man sagt auch "da", aber der Gedanke ist: Sagen wir beides oder sagen wir nur "da"?

Zusammengefasst: Ich bin der Meinung, dass wir beides sagen können aber was ich als richtiger betrachte (und was auch im Duden steht), "Da" für eine Zeitangabe und "Hier" für Lokal und Zeitangabe, aber die Zeitangabe kommt an letzter Stelle.

Ich würde auch gern dass Ihr Meinungen dazu schreibt , und natürlich auch DUDEN nachschaut, damit ihr sicherstellt, was ich gefunden habe und was man darunter verstehen kann. Villeicht habe ich falsch gelesen oder verstanden, deshalb bitte die Links unten anschauen.

Viele Grüße

BEDEUTUNGEN, BEISPIELE UND WENDUNGEN

Hier ; https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hier
Da ; https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung...verb_dort_hier

Comment: Willkommen. Ich hab mir herausgenommen, einige der Satzzeichen zu korrigieren und habe damit hoffentlich nicht den ursprünglichen Sinn verloren.

Comment: Nur nebenbei: Beide Sätze wären auch ohne irgendwelche weiteren Wörter einwandfrei verständlich.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mit Ihrer Reiseleitung haben wir uns am 12.12.2016 gegen 10 Uhr in Verbindung gesetzt! Wir bekamen auch **da** keine Hilfe.

**Da** ist der Ort, an dem die Reiseleitung sitzt. Nicht identisch mit dem Aufenthaltsort der Hilfesuchenden. Völlig eindeutig: **da**.

> Obwohl wir mehrfach darum baten, mussten wir bis zu unserer Abreise **dort** bleiben / dableiben.

Der Satz steht in der Vergangenheit. Es ist davon auszugehen, dass die schreibende Person sich nicht mehr am selben Ort befindet. Daher kann es nicht *hier* lauten. Nach dem Ausschlussprinzip also **da**, oder besser **dort**.

---

Du kannst natürlich sagen

> Ich war gestern auch schon **hier**.

wenn du dich zum Zeitpunkt der Äußerung dieses Satzes immer noch oder wieder an demselben Ort befindest.

Comment: vielen dank ! die Dame sagte zu mir , man sagt nie ich war hier ,sondern da ! das ist natürlich falsch und zeigt mir auch dass sie unerfahren ist.

Comment: Oder älter. Früher sah man das kritischer.

Comment: Zum ersten Satz: Es ist richtig, dass das gesuchte Wort keine temporale, sondern eine lokale Angabe macht. Aber besser als »da« würde »dort« passen (in österreichischem Deutsch wäre »da« sogar strikt falsch). »Da« bezeichnet einen Ort in unmittelbarer Nähe des Sprechers. Da sich der Sprecher und die Reiseleitung aber nicht am selben Ort befinden, ist in deutschem Deutsch »dort« die bessere Wahl, und in österreichischem Deutsch sogar die einzige richtige.

Comment: Klar , dort ist die beste Lösung,aber leider hatten wir entweder hier oder da,deshalb war ich auch der Meinung,dass die Lösung auf gar keinen Fall Hier gewesen wäre, Sondern da, eventuell kritisch aber bestimmt nicht falsch